# How to make one branch public while the others remain private on GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab, configuration

I am currently working on a LaTeX template. I chose gitlab to host the template.

Now I want to give some colleagues access to my template, but only to the master branch. I use the other branches to write my personal documents based on the template.

Is it possible to set the master branch to public while the other branches remain private?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert in GitLab but I would assume it to be similar to other solutions like it (bitbucket, github).

A simple way to achieve this would be to clone the repo in another private repo instead of doing a separate branch.  In effect this would work similar to having your local repo and the gitlab repo.  Merging a branch and merging with another repo is not much different with git

Answer (score 0):

Git does not have branch specific permissions.

For branch specific permissions, you need a server-side authorization layer like Gitolite — obviously, this requires you to be managing your own Git server.

Comment: so what's the actual answer to the question?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am using gitlab.com as hosting solution, is gitlab able to manage branch specific permissions?

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html

Only in enterprise edition. But follow the link above.